# Parsing through a file for only integers with exception statements, but there are unexpected zeros added?

Tags: c#

I am reading through a file that contains integers and strings. I am trying to put only the integers into an array, but it seems that where a string was, a zero takes its place. I really am not sure what is doing this. This is my try catch that does the operation. What could be making those zeros that arent supposed to be there?

```
 string[] eachString = fileContents.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               
            int[] onlyInt = new int[eachString.Length];
            int[] eachInt = new int[eachString.Length];
            int v;
            for (int i=0; i<eachString.Length;i++)
                try
                {
                    v= int.Parse(eachString[i]);
                    eachInt[i] = v;


                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    //Just ignore the line
  
                }
```

EDIT:
Here is what is in the file: 5 10 15 hello world 50 20
I am expecting the eachInt[] array to have only the 5 integers in the file. I have to sort through the array later and when I go over every element, find the smallest int and it says the answer is 0 when the smallest should be 5.

Comment: Can you share the sample content of the file? and also add some details about what is the expected behavior/output and what actually you are getting?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added some info

Comment: Hint: What happens to `eachInt[i]` if `int.Parse` throws an exception? What is the initial value for each of the items in `eachInt` (before you assign anything to individual array positions)? Aside: Use `int.TryParse` rather than catching the exception (which is slower).

Comment: @John Ohhhh. So when int.parse throws an exception at position i, eachInt[i]  would be zero at that position instead of being empty. So when I loop over it to find the smallest value, it would check those "empty" positions.

Comment: You should probably use a `List<int>` instead, since it will only have as many positions as you add items to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for your issue is how arrays are initialized. When you create an array, it is filled with the default value of the type you're creating the array with. For `int`, `default(int) == 0`, so the array is filled with zeroes. When your code fails to parse a value (because it's not an `int`), it skips over filling in a value at this position and the default value remains. This is why you're seeing zero as your lowest value.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
string[] eachString = fileContents.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<int> eachInt = new List<int>();
for (int i=0; i < eachString.Length; i++)
{
    if (int.TryParse(eachString[i], out int v))
    {
        eachInt.Add(v);
    }
}
```

Changes I've made:

1. I've changed your array to a `List<int>`, which will only contain the items you add to it.
2. I've removed your try/catch (slow) with a proactive `TryParse` approach. `TryParse` will return `false` if it is unable to parse a string or `true` when it parses it successfully.